# regarding wordpress url structure rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I want to create user friendly wordpress pages url's.
I want to make url like this for example:-

http://www.example.com/234

here 234 is any integer number assigned by admin for the pages.

when i am trying to do this then it automatically adding -2 with the url's and also page with this url is not working.
Any help for this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Supplying your .htaccess file is pretty much required if you want an answer.

Comment: You can make seo freendly urls from admin itself, you can choose different way the urls are shown and need to add .htacces in your root folder also

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your `.htaccess` file correct, you'll have a `-2` appended to the url in case you are setting a value which already exists for another post. Check your posts again to see if there's any post with that permalink (including posts saved as draft).